# Git keep tracking a file that not exists

Tags: git

I'm getting this error when I try to push to a new repository in github.

```
Remote: Error: Trace: 0e8e7c9b77ecb569f542dddcdc30ef43cc3a34213dff8e8bb937aff6aac1def6        
Remote: Error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.        
Remote: Error: File WebApi/.local-chromium/Win64-884014/chrome-win/chrome.dll is 153.38 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
Remote: Error: File WebApi/.local-chromium/Win64-884014/chrome-win/interactive_ui_tests.exe is 158.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

When I try to remove these files I get this error:

```
git rm -r --cached WebApi/.local-chromium/Win64-884014/chrome-win/chrome.dll
fatal: pathspec 'WebApi/.local-chromium/Win64-884014/chrome-win/chrome.dll' did not match any files
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: I think that's because the file is still in your git history, in an older commit and you have to rewrite the history by removing it. Because github check all the commits you will push for big files and will prevent the push. So if github found it, sure it is part of the commit history...

Comment: And you have tens of answers on the subject https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GitHub%27s+file+size+limit+of+100.00+MB